# Labeled arrow from part of equation to an element of TikZ diagram (beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows

I want to have the following in my slide: some math, and below it a diagram of two circles, and ideally, I'd want an arrow going from the `<=` sign in the math shown below, pointing to the circle on the left, with a label on the arrow; and another arrow going from the `>=` sign in the math, to the the circle on the right, and again with a label on the arrow.

As of now, I just tried a simpler thing, which is to just have an arrow pointing to the circle, with the label. However, the circles get shifted too far out to the right, to the point that the second circle isn't visible at all. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{rose} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%% packages I am adding
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz} %for beautiful inline highlighted math. Thanks Claudio! 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing, patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}
\usepackage{skull}

\usepackage{nccmath} %for \medmath command to fit long eqns in tcolorbox
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}


%\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, overlay]

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand\fiteq[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd\mybox>.85\textwidth\resizebox{.85\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \else\usebox{\mybox}\fi%
}

\newtcbtheorem[]{mydef}{Problem Statement}{colframe=white, colback=white}{ps}

\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mydef}
%% start1
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{title}

    \begin{mydef}{}{probStatement}
        Here is some math       
        \begin{equation*}
        \tcboxmath[colframe=red, colback=white, left = 0.5 mm, right=0.5 mm, top = 0.35mm, bottom = 0.35mm]
        {f(x) = ??, g(x) \leq P(x), h(x) \geq ???}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{mydef}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ 
    packnode/.style = {
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center
            }, 
    packcircle/.style={
            circle, 
            minimum size = 120pt, 
            draw = black, 
            thick, 
            dashed}]      
        \coordinate (c) at (2.2, 7); 

        \node(bigcircle) at (c) [style=packcircle, visible on=<5->]{};

        \coordinate (cCovering) at (8.5, 7); 
        \draw[black, thick, visible on=<6->](cCovering) circle (45 pt);

\node [above, left = of bigcircle, xshift  = - 3cm, minimum width=0pt, style = packnode, visible on = <6->]  (mypacknode) {label \\ this};
\draw [stealth-,out=250,in=150, visible on = <6->] (bigcircle) to (mypacknode.north west);%%%%%%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you only see one label you have the additional node far left of the left circle so that not everything fits on one page. So I decreased some distances. As for the arrows to the inequality signs, this is a job for `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{rose} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%% packages I am adding
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz} %for beautiful inline highlighted math. Thanks Claudio! 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{nccmath} %for \medmath command to fit long eqns in tcolorbox
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}


%\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, overlay]

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand\fiteq[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd\mybox>.85\textwidth\resizebox{.85\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \else\usebox{\mybox}\fi%
}

\newtcbtheorem[]{mydef}{Problem Statement}{colframe=white, colback=white}{ps}

\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mydef}
%% start1
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{title}

    \begin{mydef}{}{probStatement}
        Here is some math       
        \begin{equation*}
        \tcboxmath[colframe=red, colback=white, left = 0.5 mm, right=0.5 mm, top = 0.35mm, bottom = 0.35mm]
        {f(x) = ??, g(x) \tikzmarknode{leq}{\leq} P(x)\;,\quad 
            h(x) \tikzmarknode{geq}{\geq} ???}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{mydef}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, 
    packnode/.style = {
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center
            }, 
    packcircle/.style={
            circle, 
            minimum size = 120pt, 
            draw = black, 
            thick, 
            dashed}]      
        \coordinate (c); 
        \begin{scope}[visible on=<5->]
         \node(bigcircle) at (c) [style=packcircle]{};
         \draw[stealth-,overlay] (bigcircle) to[out=120,in=-90] 
          node[pos=0.2,left]{$\lambda_1$}(leq);
        \end{scope} 
        %
        \begin{scope}[visible on=<6->]
         \node[black, thick,circle,inner sep=0pt,draw,
            minimum size=45pt,right=2em of bigcircle](cCovering){};
         \draw[stealth-,overlay] (cCovering) to[out=45,in=-90] 
          node[midway,above]{$\lambda_2$} (geq);
         \node [above, left=2em of bigcircle,  minimum width=0pt, style =
          packnode, visible on = <6->]  (mypacknode) {label \\ this};
         \draw [stealth-,out=250,in=150, visible on = <6->,looseness=1.5] (bigcircle) 
          to (mypacknode.north west);%%%%%%
        \end{scope} 

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another version in which the circles are symmetric about the center of the page. That is, the middle of shortest line connecting the circles is horizontally in the middle of the page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{rose} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%% packages I am adding
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz} %for beautiful inline highlighted math. Thanks Claudio! 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{nccmath} %for \medmath command to fit long eqns in tcolorbox
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}


%\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, overlay]

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand\fiteq[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd\mybox>.85\textwidth\resizebox{.85\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \else\usebox{\mybox}\fi%
}

\newtcbtheorem[]{mydef}{Problem Statement}{colframe=white, colback=white}{ps}

\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mydef}
%% start1
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{title}

    \begin{mydef}{}{probStatement}
        Here is some math       
        \begin{equation*}
        \tcboxmath[colframe=red, colback=white, left = 0.5 mm, right=0.5 mm, top = 0.35mm, bottom = 0.35mm]
        {f(x) = ??, g(x) \tikzmarknode{leq}{\leq} P(x)\;,\quad 
            h(x) \tikzmarknode{geq}{\geq} ???}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{mydef}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, 
    packnode/.style = {
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center
            }, 
    packcircle/.style={
            circle, 
            minimum size = 120pt, 
            draw = black, 
            thick, 
            dashed}]      

        \begin{scope}[visible on=<5->]
         \node[style=packcircle,left=1em of current page.center,
         yshift=-4em](bigcircle) {};
         \draw[stealth-] (bigcircle) to[out=120,in=-90] 
          node[pos=0.2,above]{$\lambda_1$}(leq);
        \end{scope} 
        %
        \begin{scope}[visible on=<6->]
         \node[black, thick,circle,inner sep=0pt,draw,
            minimum size=45pt,right=2em of bigcircle](cCovering){};
         \draw[stealth-] (cCovering) to[out=45,in=-90] 
          node[midway,right]{$\lambda_2$} (geq);
         \node [above, left=3em of bigcircle.240,  minimum width=0pt, style =
          packnode, visible on = <6->]  (mypacknode) {label \\ this};
         \draw [stealth-, visible on = <6->] (bigcircle) 
          to[out=-100,in=-40,looseness=1.5] (mypacknode.-45);%%%%%%
        \end{scope} 

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The one issue with this is that the circles are still both quite to the right. Would it be possible to shift them both to the left, so that they are placed symmetrically on the page (ie, their centres are symmetric about the two vertical halves of the page). And the label "label this" can be removed, since you already took care of it in the "lambda_1" label. Thank you!

Comment: @lazulikid I added such a version.

Comment: Thank you!! I still have a question -- when I run this code as it is, it does exactly what you show here. But when I integrate with my code, the arrow starts not from the \leq or \geq, but from some completely arbitrary point :( Do you happen to have any guesses as to why this is behaving so?

Comment: @lazulikid Obviously I posted what I got. Let me guess: you compile with `XeLaTeX`?

Comment: No, I compiled with pdflatex. I'll try to change things one at a time to see this issue. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry I have one last question -- in my original code, I needed the coordinate ```c``` since I used it as a center for other circles and ellipses, co-centric with the left circle (similarly there was a center for the right circle used for the same purpose). In your new code, you got rid of this center. If I wish to now refer to this center, is there a way I can do that? (I need it just to center the other circles and ellipses)

Comment: @lazulikid This coordinate is simply `(bigcircle.center)`. (In this case the `.center` coordinate is really at the center.;-)